# Load XML string from $_POST array

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I receive a $_POST array from a system after a certain action has been performed on a database. I've tried accesing the array and saving it as an simple_xml object. So far I have not succeeded. The array which is being sent looks like this.

```
Array
(
     [xml] => <?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
     <callback><profile><id>313009</id><fields><email>tomkriek@gmail.com</email><nieuwsbrief>8</nieuwsbrief></fields><interests></interests></profile><action>update</action><parameters><nieuwsbrief>8</nieuwsbrief></parameters></callback>
)
```

I've tried storing this as a simple_xml object like this.

```
if($xml_test = simplexml_load_string($_POST['xml']))
{
    $xml_test->saveXML('test.xml');
}
```

I can save a different kind of .xml file so I'm sure the permissions are set right.
As for the rest I'm not that familiar with formatting and parsing .xml files so I hope anyone could help a hand with this.

My desired outcome is that I can access the newly made simple_xml object and access the values and fields.

Comment: Trying a var_dump() on the array seeing what else is in it.
had it on print_r()

Comment: What errors are you getting?  Set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to `stripslashes()`:

```
$string = stripslashes($_POST['xml']);

if($xml_test = simplexml_load_string($string))
{
    $xml_test->saveXML('test.xml');
}
```

It would be better to turn off `magic_quotes_gpc` in php.ini:

Comment: Well spot. I hadn't noticed that the input is not valid XML.

Comment: Thank you that did it. Was it the `<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>` part which made it a non valid xml string?

Answer (score 0):

saveXML() will write out the XML into the file. If you want to access the XML elements you will need to do so by doing something like

```
    $action = $xml_test->action;
    echo $action;
```

You can try printing out the simplexml object so you can see its structure of it by doing

```
    print_r($xml_test);
```